# How to link a specific option from select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add a link to a specific option on select? I tried `on change` but it's not working.

```
$('.js-select-manage-edit').on('change', function() {
  alert( 'Hey!' );
});
```

My **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/c9xkacms/2/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `select` element as selector and check if selected option has the desire class(`.js-select-manage-edit`) and redirect to external url:

```
$('select.form-control').on('change', function () {
    if ($("option:selected", this).hasClass("js-select-manage-edit")) {
        window.open(this.value);
    }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4u4yqpnq/)

Comment: Thank you. I just had to add window.location.replace(this.value); to open the link on the same tab.

Comment: @brunodd Glad that I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand expected behaviour, you want to open new link depending specific option selected:

```
$('.form-control').on('change', function() {
    if($(':selected', this).hasClass('js-select-manage-edit'))
        window.open(this.value); // or window.location = this.value; (depending expected behaviour)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your change event should be bound to the `select`. Then you could do something like this...

```js
$('.my-select').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).find(":selected").attr('value')) {
        window.location = $(this).val(); // won't work in snippet
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control my-select">
                <option>select</option>
                <option class="js-select-manage-edit" value="http://www.google.com">Item with link</option>
                <option>No link here</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```